# Flex AdvancedDataGrid (mx) How can I get the dataGrid item on a mouseWheel Event

Tags: apache-flex, events, mousewheel, advanceddatagrid

I have an (mx) **AdvancedDataGrid** and when I use the wheel on my mouse, I want to capture the item in my dataGrid that I moused over using the wheel on my mouse.

I added: `mouseWheel="doMouseWheel(event)"` and in the event, I need to be able to find the item in my dataGrid that I moused over using the mouse wheel.

I know that you can get the `event.delta`, but not sure where to go from there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... the data is under:   event.target.data